# Troubles editing a django login view

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I want to add 2FA to my django app. I found [this library](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth) but there is some thing i am not understanding. On their [example django app](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/tree/master/example) they are using the module's login view, it means that the example app does not have its own view, so how do i integrate the 2fa module into my own app?

There are two possible ways here:

1) Yes, i could just use their view but the problem is that in the future i want to add other features to my login, so the problem will be: how do i edit the view if i'm using their login view?

2) I could integrate the two fa into my already existing login view (**see below**), but the problem is that i don't know how to do that.

Any advice?

this is what my login views looks like at the moment:

```
def login_request(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
            form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                    return redirect("example:home")
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")

            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")
```